# How can I make these enums a const

Tags: typescript1.4

I presently have the enum which works fine.

```
export enum LEADER {
    /** tab leader is nothing. */
    NONE = ' '.charCodeAt(0),
    /** tab leader is dots. */
    DOT = '.'.charCodeAt(0),
    /** tab leader is dots. */
    MIDDLE_DOT = '\''.charCodeAt(0),
    /** tab leader is hyphens. */
    HYPHEN = '-'.charCodeAt(0),
    /** tab leader is underscores. */
    UNDERSCORE = '_'.charCodeAt(0),
}
```

But I want to make them a const enum. Is there a way to do this without my looking up what the hex code is for each character value I'm using?

thanks - dave

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, as far as I understand.
const enum values must be constant expressions - so either 0, 1, 72.  In this case, you are calculating the value at runtime - and therefore it is not a constant expression.
For const enums, the compiler will not convert the enum into a JavaScript class - it will just replace the const value in the code with the corresponsing value.  So this code :

```
const enum LEADER {
    NONE = 72,
}

var testValue = LEADER.NONE;
```

just becomes this JavaScript:

```
var testValue = 72 /* NONE */;
```

Hope this helps.